# powershell user input validation not accepting valid input

Tags: validation, powershell, input

I have some code which is behaving strangely and I am not sure why. I am attempting to validate the user input is a number and that it is less than 255. Pretty easy.

Problem is that numbers from 26 to 99 are not valid for me in my testing. 1-25 are fine, and 100+ seem fine too.. but for some reason 26-99 keep me in the loop.

```
DO
{
$ip_addr_first = Read-Host 'enter a number less than 255'
} while ($ip_addr_first -notmatch '\p{Nd}+' -or $ip_addr_first -gt 255) 

write-host 'You entered' $ip_addr_first
```

suggestions welcome on where the problem is, as I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
do
{
  $ip_addr_first = Read-Host 'Enter an integer between 0 and 255'
} while ($ip_addr_first -notmatch '^\p{Nd}+$' -or [int] $ip_addr_first -gt 255) 

write-host 'You entered:' $ip_addr_first
```

Note the `[int]` cast, which ensures that `$ip_addr_first` is compared as a *number*, which makes all the difference here.

Without it, given that `$ip_addr_first` is a *string* (the type returned by `Read-Host`), `-gt` performs *lexical* comparison, and `26` is *lexically* greater than `255`, for instance (the same applies to any number (string) starting with `3` or greater).

Also note that I've *anchored* your regular expression `p{Nd}+` with `^` and `$` to ensure that the *entire* input is matched against it (you could make this more permissive by allowing leading and trailing whitespace).

---

Alternative approach that uses number parsing only:

```
[int] $ip_addr_first = -1
do
{
  $userInput = Read-Host 'Enter an integer between 0 and 255'
} while (-not ([int]::TryParse($userInput, [ref] $ip_addr_first) -and
               $ip_addr_first -ge 0 -and $ip_addr_first -le 255)) 

write-host 'You entered:' $ip_addr_first
```

Comment: thanks... the cast is a new one for me since I'm just learning Powershell

Comment: @PS_newbie: My pleasure; in PowerShell you often don't have to worry about types, but on occasion you do - generally, it's worth understanding the underlying (.NET) types and how they can be inspected (`Get-Member`) and converted. My alternative solution shows you how to type-constrain a variable during initialization (a persistent cast, in a manner of speaking).